# Reusing keywords for search

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make a search feature where the user searches tags which are appended to different articles, like: PC, health, fashion clothing... etc.
My current table is like this:

```
Tag_id  | Tag            | Article_id
-----------------------------------
1       | scary          |   2
-----------------------------------
2       | daunting       |   2
-----------------------------------
3       | chilling       |   2
-----------------------------------
4       | creepy         |   2
-----------------------------------
5       | scary          |   5
-----------------------------------
6       | daunting       |   5
-----------------------------------
7       | chilling       |   5
-----------------------------------
8       | creepy         |   5
```

As you can see there are synonyms for each tag, which have to be repeated at every article which share the same tags. My question is this: what table structure would allow tags to be reused (no repeated tags), and at the same time not search friendly. (a normal thesaurus can't be used, because the tags are something short phrases and slang)

Comment: Basic LEFT JOIN structure with three tables: `articles`, `tags` and `article_tags`. And I would add an `alias_of_tag_id` column to your current table to easily find tag alias links for a given tag. In short, this is basic SQL design. You might try reading a book on it before you start working with it :)

Comment: this table structure still requires to associate each tag (and synonyms) with its article in the article_tags table, which is not what i want (sorry if I wasn't precise enough). I was thinking more of something where each article was assigned a main-tag (most commonly used word), which would be referenced to by its synonyms...

Comment: Just use the `alias_of_tag_id` column suggestion. If you're 100% sure you never want to allow multiple tag associations with a single article (probably not a good idea), then simply add a `tag_id` column to your `articles` table and eliminate the linking table. As I said, these are pretty basic database design concepts. I would recommend doing some reading on the technology before employing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You want three tables:

```
ARTICLE
id   (a primary uid)
link (links to the article)

TAG
id   (a primary uid)
name (ie 'chilling')

ARTICLETAG
article (a foreign key: a uid that exists in ARTICLE)
tag     (a foreign key: a uid that exists in TAG)
```

Each time you want to tag an article, you insert into `ARTICLETAG` a new row with the article you want to tag and the id of the tag you want to tag it with. Add to `TAG` and `ARTICLE` as needed for new articles and tags.

Answer (score 0):

**ARTICLE TABLE**

> -id -- UNIQUE (auto incremental or not, you decide)
>
> -More attributes...

**TAGS TABLE**

> -id -- UNIQUE (auto incremental or not, you decide)
>
> -tag

Relational table
**ARTICLE_TAG TABLE**

> -article_id
>
> -tag_id

You can relate as many tags with articles you want